# Login screen keeps on loading indefinitely after selecting the account

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-play-services

#### 1: Environment

- Device: ONEPLUS 6
- OS version: ANDROID 10
- SDK version: 29
- [Android] Google Play Services version: 19.2.0

#### 2: Problem:

##### Steps to reproduce:

1. Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(gApiClient);
2. startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);

##### Observed Results:

- Login screen keeps on loading indefinitely after selecting the account

##### Expected Results:

- onActivityResult  should get called with signin data

##### Relevant Code:

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                          .requestIdToken(Constant.serverclientid) // required to get accesstoken
                          .requestScopes(new Scope(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM))
                          .requestEmail()
                          .build();

                  GoogleApiClient gApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                          .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                          .build();

                  ConnectionResult c = gApiClient.blockingConnect();

                  if (c.isSuccess() && gApiClient.isConnected()) {
                      Log.e(TAG,"connectionResult = success");
                      gApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect().await();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Log.e(TAG,"connectionResult is failure");
                  }

                  GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getApplicationContext(), gso);
                  mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess();

                //  Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

                  Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(gApiClient);

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {

                          Log.d(TAG,"request account picker");

                          Aloading_spinner.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                          startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);


                      }
                  });
```

#### 3: LOG

```
E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT. App: _packagename_, Service: oauth2:email https://mail.google.com/ openid profile
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the exact same problem